# Low bitrate when writing from /dev/urandom to /dev/null

Tags: macos, dd

now for something completely different. I've got a Mac server and I got to continuously dd-write from /dev/urandom to /dev/null, efficiently. And now the data transfer speed is only about 11Mb/s. This feels wrong for me and I would like to increase the speed.

What should I check first?

Is it slow randomize algorithm, maybe some features are not supported by my CPU, or is it the kernel dropping the data to /dev/null too much slowly? I could use /dev/random instead, but it's less preferable for carrying less positive Qi.
Maybe I should rebuild the kernel tweaking some features? Oh I know, that's Mac and supposedly I cannot rebuild the kernel... Will Ubuntu write to /dev/null faster?

Comment: Its not the writing to /dev/null thats the bottleneck, its.the creation of random data. How random do you need random to be?

Comment: It must be totally random. Not having this, I will never end my Qi harmonizing experiment.

Comment: In that case, forget it. You should not even be using urandom, you should (at best) be using /dev/random as /dev/urandom is not totally random (arguably /dev/random isnt either, but its a lot better). Your understanding of /dev/random and other things is incorrect.

Comment: @davidgo https://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ `FreeBSD does the right thing: they don't have the distinction between /dev/random and /dev/urandom, both are the same device.`

Comment: @davidgo you're rather incorrect yourself in that case, for Macos' *random devices are totally same (as in freebsd, of which Mac OS is a sibling). And speaking of Linux, urandom is good enough for general crypto purposes. I believe a good crypto developer will know how to circumvent hypothetical insecureness of urandom.

Comment: But maybe, I should upgrade my /dev/null, to make it faster... Is there any patches for /dev/null boosting?